# How should I read formulas using multiple variables with the same name?

Tags: pronunciation

I am reading computer science texts, which tend to include a lot of summations and set logic. In set logic, formulas commonly use a capitalized variable to reference a whole set, i.e. $\Omega$, and a lowercase variable to represent a given member, i.e. $\omega$. Given that, how does one read something like:

$$
0\leq Pr(\omega)\leq 1\mathrm{\quad and \quad}\sum_{\omega\in\Omega}{Pr(\omega)} = 1
$$

Perhaps it's due to my [poor] command of math, but I tend to read this out loud to myself, and it's odd to say "The sum of the probability of omega, where omega is a member of omega..."

Comment: It may look like "The sum of the probability of omega, where omega is a member of omega...", but usually $\Omega$ is called either the 'sample space' or the 'universe' to make the distinction.

Comment: What about big omega ? It is also a good exercise to recall the nature of the entities like "the sum over all *elements* [[small] omega] in the *set* [big omega]..."

Comment: One could say "little" and "big" omega to distinguish or refer to $\Omega$ as capital omega.

Comment: http://forvo.com/word/omega/ splits the debate into o-mega and ohm-ega

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I would not use greek letters when speaking out loud if it is not necessary. I would say something like

> All probabilities are between $0$ and $1$, and the sum of all probabilities from the sample space is $1$.